# Notice: Undefined variable in function +=

Tags: php

In a couple scripts which I've created I get the same error when I connect on my wampserver.

Every thing is running smooth but I don't like those errors.
`Notice: Undefined variable`

the `$watdan` function is giving me this error.

For example I've to amounts that need to be count up: `2835 + 11024` I've already multipled those.
Now when I use this code:

```
            $total[0] = $totaal->amount;
            $total[1] = $totaal->price;
            $watdan += $total[0] * $total[1];
```

Im getting the right answer `13859` but I'm also getting the error which I've mentioned.

Now when I add `$watdan=0;` I only get the `11024` without the given error.

this is the full code:

```
    $pak14 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM log_drops INNER JOIN log_items ON log_drops.item = log_items.name AND log_drops.game = log_items.game WHERE log_drops.log_id = '".$id."' ORDER BY log_drops.log_name ASC") or die($db->error);
    while($totaal = $pak14->fetch_object())
    {

            $total[0] = $totaal->amount;
            $total[1] = $totaal->price;
            $watdan += $total[0] * $total[1];
        } 
    if(isset($watdan))
    {
        echo $watdan; echo ' Gold';
    }
```

Comment: is `$watdan` defined from before

Comment: No, I need to multiple and then that amount to add up. Thats which I don't get. If i use $watdan = 0; he doesn't count up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not Declare the variable `$watdan`. Declare variable with `0` or `''` after use it.

```
$watdan=0;//add this in your code
$total[0] = $totaal->amount;
$total[1] = $totaal->price;
$watdan += $total[0] * $total[1];
```

check this

```
 $pak14 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM log_drops INNER JOIN log_items ON log_drops.item = log_items.name AND log_drops.game = log_items.game WHERE log_drops.log_id = '".$id."' ORDER BY log_drops.log_name ASC") or die($db->error);
$watdan=0;//add this in your code
while($totaal = $pak14->fetch_object())
{

        $total[0] = $totaal->amount;
        $total[1] = $totaal->price;
        $watdan += $total[0] * $total[1];
    } 
if(isset($watdan))
{
    echo $watdan; echo ' Gold';
}
```

Comment: I need first to multiple then to count it, now he doesn't count the amount.

Comment: @JustRandomGuy provide example or edit question for better understanding what you say?

Comment: @JustRandomGuy provide your full code

Comment: I've added the OP topic

Comment: Declare the $watdan=0; above the while loop

Comment: Thank you very much, learned something new! You guys helped me alot, now I can change those errors on my other scripts!

Answer (score 2):

you have to initialize this variable to 0(zero first)

```
            $watdan=0;
            $total[0] = $totaal->amount;
            $total[1] = $totaal->price;
            $watdan += $total[0] * $total[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare first your $watdan variable as:

```
 $watdan = 0;
```

Then it will work. You can not directly assign value to variable without declare it with short hand operators.